# Which authors developed the concepts of antitypes? Which denominations of Christianity think in terms of them?

Tags: typology

Which authors developed the concepts of antitypes?
Why did they choose that kind of language?
Which denominations of Christianity think in terms of types and antitypes?

Comment: Paul did: Romans 5:14 Well he may not have used the term antitype, but he explicitly does use typology terminology there.

Comment: . . . . . and also Galatians 4:25. It is a common theme in scripture. I don't see the point of catalogueing denominations which do or don't read their bibles very well.